# Revert Joomla 2.5.18 to 2.5.16, how?

Tags: joomla-2.5, update

I have a site which was at the 2.5.16 version of Joomla, and I updated it to 2.5.18. And made new articles, changes to menus, etc.

After the update, I didn't realize that the site was very broken in the category view (due to the overrides in the views, this was the first time that happened, version 2.5.18 introduced a language parameter and my overrides didn't have that).

So, I tried to revert from 2.5.18 to 2.5.16 from my backed up files, but it didn't work that well! (no way to log in into the admin, or in the front end, it showed a blank page).

I read that it had to do with the session, or cookies, and I tried emptying them, but no luck.

I then understood that it was due to some change to the database, but I've never 
seen an update to a minor version that made a change to the database. I couldn't restore my backup of the database, because I made changes to the articles already in the 2.5.18 version. (NOTE: I made a copy of the site and restored the database to the backed up, and the login worked, which means it is definitely the database!).

**Does anyone know if it is confirmed that the database was changed, and how to revert it properly to version 2.5.16?**

Or is it related to something else?

Comment: Could you give more information about your backups? How did you make them? How did you restore them?

Comment: @moomoochoo the backups were made using akeeba backup, I restored using their install.

Comment: @moomoochoo after the restore it says 2.5.16 as expected.

Comment: I've reread your question and am confused on a number of points. Please tell me if the following sentences are correct. `1`-You have successfully restored a backup of joomla 2.5.16. `2`- You want to keep your articles and menu changes that you made in 2.5.18, but need to revert the Joomla version back to 2.5.16. `3`- you tried to manually revert back from 2.5.18 to 2.5.16 -when you did you saw a white screen and couldn't login. Are these points correct?

Comment: @moomoochoo `1` not sucessfully restored, because it had to be a partial restore (just the files), and so I left the database unchanged, which lead to point `3` which is a blank page after trying the login; `2` is desired but I would rather keep the database untouched.

Comment: If you use firebug, can you go to the white page and tell us any errors you see.

Comment: @moomoochoo it was indeed related to the user table! I retested it and it works now, so Anibal's answer is correcto :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Joomla 2.5.18, a new Password Security, based on PHPass, was introduced.

When a returning user visits your site, the password is encrypted with the new method.

There's no database structure change. http://developer.joomla.org/version-2-5-18-release-notes.html

Comment: What about Joomla 2.5.17?

Comment: hmm, I think I restored the user table and it didn't work (kept giving me a blank page for the login), I'm going to try it again just to make sure.

Comment: Any database changes will be put in the relevent files here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/2.5.x/administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql and there have been no changes since 2.5.10 :)

Comment: I just tried it again, files from 2.5.16, database from 2.5.18 and only restoring the user to the 2.5.16 table, and (after a false error due to a cache/session problem which lead me to believe it didn't work) it works! the password has changed indeed (looking at the password in the db they are different), so you answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is a bit off topic but you really should fix the layout problem of the category. That would be much easier and from security point of view a necessary step.

Or would you like to stay on an old version, that maybe become a security problem?

Comment: Updating the overrides is my objective, but I have this topic stuck in my mind because I never understood if it was indeed the database or not. At the moment I have everything in 2.5.18 but the com_component with all the files of 2.5.16 and it works, but obviously it is not a good idea.